# Center on a country by name in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Would someone tell me how to center on a country by name on the Google Maps API v3? I know how to do it in v2, but need to do it in v3.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You could use Geocoding to lookup the Lat/Lng of the country. Take a look at this [sample](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple.html) from Google.

Basically you need to do something like this:

```
var country = "Germany";
var geocoder;

geocoder.geocode( {'address' : country}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    }
});
```

In your initialize function you'll need to set the value of the geocoder object, like this:

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

You'd need to workout what an appropriate zoom level would be, and then set that after you have centered the map.

Comment: I thinks this is the cleanest and simplest way to re-position the map... Thanks :)

Comment: @kzhen this works but it doesn't zoom in that much on some countries like Australia. is there a way to alter this?

Answer (score 3):

**This code working for me:**

```
      let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      let location = "England";
      geocoder.geocode({ 'address': location }, function(results, status){
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          } else {
              alert("Could not find location: " + location);
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do it would be by having a list of the countries and their respective Lat and Lng, with that information known you could use the following code.

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
```

Out of curiosity, how would you do it in v2?

Comment: you could pass the country name to the geocoder provided in the API, and use the resultant lat/lon just as you've done there.

Comment: for reference, here you can find a list of countries and their respective center points:
https://github.com/mihai-craita/countries_center_box